# Legacy tables grails mapping issue with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, grails, grails-domain-class

I have 2 legacy tables into SQL Server:

- This is the first one --> http://ur1.ca/hl1mi
- This the second table --> http://ur1.ca/hl1mr

An these are my domain classes for these tables

- Taladro.groovy -->  http://ur1.ca/hl1mw
- Proyecto.groovy --> http://ur1.ca/hl1n8

When I try to insert a Taladro into the database using the dinamic scaffolding fails with these error:

**ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'proyecto_id', table 'Portal.ORECONTROL.TALADROS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.**

I change the name of the foreign key from id_proyecto to IdMalla as are in the legacy tables (See http://ur1.ca/hl1mw).

I'm using a SQL Server 2008 as Database server

Answer (score 0):

Seems that now you have column `proyecto_id` in `TALADROS` table with not-null constraint. In domain object `Taladro` you have specified association column mapping as `'IdMalla'` instead of default `'proyecto_id'`. 
Obviously that means that column proyecto_id is not filled and since it has not-null constraint, you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I can resolve the problem renaming the domain classes with name of the tables in the database and changing the name of the foreign key to "IdMalla". Thanks all for the answers